# Multiple connections to the Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, lan, 3g

I have an internet connection via institute lan and another via a 3G stick. I want my chrome to use 3G connection and my `ie` to use LAN. Can this be achieved?

Also, I have a virtual machine and I want the vm to use LAN connection.

Thanks

Comment: Look at [How to keep multiple connections to internet?](http://superuser.com/q/1329), [Multiple Wi-Fi cards and Internet connections on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/140607), [Multiple network connections on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/313679)

Comment: First part of [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/1969/99868) about ForceBindIP, if to be precise